# Convert parent back to child without casting

Tags: c++, polymorphism, abstract-class

I'm creating a collision system for a game and having a range of bounding volume classes (AABB, OBB, 18DOP etc) and they're a child of "GameObjectElement" (abstract class). The idea being each game object can hold a vector of GameObjectElements.

The problem is if I create an AABB and attach it to a GameObject is now becomes a GameObjectElement. However, to check for a collision, I need it to be an AABB not a GameObjectElement.

My first instinct was to use casting but during university, my lecturer despised this. I've looked at polymorphism and upcasting and downcasting but can't quite piece together a solution (though I think I have all the pieces to the puzzle).

If anyone can suggest a way to fix this problem, it'd be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Side note: If your vector contains `GameObjectElement` types, you'll potentially run into object slicing issues. If it holds pointers to `GameObjectElement` types, you could have poor performance due to constant cache misses if the objects aren't stored in memory in a cache-friendly configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store various members of a class hierarchy, you usually use pointers. (Other possibilities are variants and 'chameleon classes' of same size). This is because vectors need to store elements of the same type and size. What you need here is a pure virtual function for collision checking (e.g. `virtual bool collision(const int x, const int y) = 0`) in the base class, an implementation of that virtual function in each descendant (e.g., `virtual bool collision(const int x, const int y) { return x == m_x && y==m_y; }`) and to store pointers to base in the vector (e.g. `std::vector<GameObjectElement*> v`). Then - miracle happens :) - calling `v[i]->collision(x, y)` will call the apropriate implementation in the descendant. Be sure to allocate elements with `new` and deallocate with `delete` - or just use `shared_ptr<GameObjectElement>` if you want to make it very simple in one cal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I've never seen this before, sounds awesome! I'm a bit busy atm but I'll give it a go when i get the chance ^^

Comment: Your suggestion sounds perfect except for one thing, when I call v[i]->collision(x, y), I need x and y to actual be the derived class as it needs to be an AABB for the AABB check or an OBB for the OBB check, whilst if i call it in a loop as suggested such as v[i]->collision(AABB); AABB is going to be a GameObjectElement

Answer (score 0):

If the selection of colission algorithm depends on the type of both instances, you are looking for a *Double dispatch* mechanism, which can be implemented in c++ using the *Visitor pattern*

The Wikipedia page actually has an example that covers collision of objects :)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_is_more_than_function_overloading

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Never heard of this before so learning more. Finding it kinda confusing though, so going to read up some more ^^